# Как в ListView отобразить данные от другого Activity, вызванного через ItemClick?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть два активити. В одном находится ListView, а в другом поля, где я выбираю параметры. 
По нажатию на какую-нибудь строку в LV я вызываю вторую активити (оно одно для всех строк) и там настраиваю нужные мне параметры. Потом эти данные я должен отобразить в LV. В каждой строке будут отображаться свои данные.
Как сделать так, чтобы второе активити было индивидуальным для каждой строки LV? 
Я знаю, что это как-то связано с id пункта листа, но я не знаю, как это все организовать.

Comment: добавьте нужную информацию в запускающий активити `intent` через `intent.putExtra(key, value)` (например - тот же айди позиции), а во второй активности считывайте его через `getIntent().getIntExtra(key, defaultValue)` (вместо `getIntExtra` можно использовать и получение других типов)

Comment: Я так сделал, но он все равно запускает активити как для одной строки. В итоге одни и те же параметры во всех строках.

Comment: ну по идее, нужно передавать значение из списка, привязанного к LV. А вообще, сейчас этот виджет считается устаревшим, `RecyclerView` более прост и удобен в использовании.

Comment: переопределяем lv.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { потом запускаем активность с "экстрой", в активности ловим - все работает

Comment: посмотрите , как работает стандартный шаблон студии master detail flow, там как раз реализована такая возможность. для возврата значения в вызывающюю активити используется вызов второй активити через startActivityForResult()